# R - mutate for string processing - not getting the behavior I was hoping for

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I'm trying to use mutate in dplyr to process strings and I'm not getting the output that I want (see below) where instead of operating line by line, mutate is taking the first element and populating it downward.  I was wondering if someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to tweak this code to work properly.

```
short.idfun = function(longid) 
{
    x      = strsplit(longid,"_")
    y      = x[[1]]
    study  = substr(y[1],8,nchar(y[1]))
    subj   = y[length(y)]
    subj   = substr(subj,regexpr("[^0]",subj),nchar(subj)) #remove leading zeros
    shortid= paste(study,subj,sep="-")
    return(shortid)
}

data = data.frame(test=c("1234567Andy_003_003003","1234567Beth_004_003004","1234567Char_003_003005"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data= mutate(data,shortid=short.idfun(test))
print(data)

#### Below is my output
#                       test   shortid
#1    1234567Andy_003_003003 Andy-3003
#2    1234567Beth_004_003004 Andy-3003
#3    1234567Char_003_003005 Andy-3003

#### This is the behavior I was hoping for
#                       test   shortid
#1    1234567Andy_003_003003 Andy-3003
#2    1234567Beth_004_003004 Beth-3004
#3    1234567Char_003_003005 Char-3005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is the use of `rowwise()`:

```
data %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(shortid = short.idfun(test))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#Groups: <by row>
#
#                    test   shortid
#                   (chr)     (chr)
#1 1234567Andy_003_003003 Andy-3003
#2 1234567Beth_004_003004 Beth-3004
#3 1234567Char_003_003005 Char-3005
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a nice approach!

Comment: @AndyStein Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your function needs a little help vectorizing.  You can run it through `vapply` to get what you're after.

```
data = data.frame(test=c("1234567Andy_003_003003","1234567Beth_004_003004","1234567Char_003_003005"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data= mutate(data,
             shortid=vapply(test, short.idfun, character(1)))
print(data)
```

To see why you got the result you did, we can look at little at the first few lines of your function.

```
longid = data$test
(x <- strsplit(longid, "_"))
[[1]]
[1] "1234567Andy" "003"         "003003"     

[[2]]
[1] "1234567Beth" "004"         "003004"     

[[3]]
[1] "1234567Char" "003"         "003005"
```

Everything looks good so far, but now you define `y`.

```
(y      = x[[1]])

[1] "1234567Andy" "003"         "003003"
```

By calling `x[[1]]`, you pulled out only the first element of `x`, not the first vector in `x`, not the first element of each vector in `x`.  You could also revise your function by defining `y <= vapply(x, function(v) v[1], character(1))` and skip the `vapply` in `mutate`.  Either way should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I guess this is a case where I should just use lappy/vapply instead of mutate.  I'm a little confused about when to use what, but I guess what you're saying is that mutate is only for vectorized functions.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `mutate` in this situation.  And there's no reason you can't use an apply function within `mutate` (I do it all the time). I think what caught you in this case is that you expected `strsplit` to return something like a matrix.  As you get more familiar with what functions return, you'll start to work around these kinds of problems before they show up as errors in your code.  Just takes a little time and experience.